# Name column not matching in query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007, union

I have following table:

w2001

```
Code  Name    
1     abc
2     xyz
3     pqr
7     OPW
```

and a second table:

w2011

```
Code  Name
4     abc
2     xyz
5     pqr
6     MNS
```

I would like the following result:

```
Code2001 Code2011  Name
1         4        abc
2         2        xyz
3         5        pqr
7         -        OPW
-         6        MNS
```

I've tried this query:

```
select distinct b.name as 2001 
  from w2001 a, w2011 b
 where b.name not in ( select a.name from w2001 )
```

This did not work, also tried:

```
select a.code as Code2001 , b.code as Code2011  ,*
  from w2001 a, w2011 b
 where a.name = b.name
```

But this didn't work either; how should I get the result?

Comment: Have you considered _why_ they didn't work? P.S. You're looking for a FULL OUTER JOIN; http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14441/full-outer-join-in-ms-access

Comment: join expression not supported error

Comment: I'm 100% certain that MS-Access 2007 supports JOIN, so you've probably incremented it incorrectly... If you [edit] your question then people might be able to see and help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With another database, you could use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` to get the result you want.  However, Access does not support full joins.  Fortunately, you can `UNION` a `LEFT JOIN` with a `RIGHT JOIN` to accomplish the same thing.

```sql
SELECT
    w2001.Code AS Code2001,
    w2011.Code AS Code2011,
    w2001.Name
FROM
    w2001 LEFT JOIN w2011
    ON w2001.Name = w2011.Name
UNION
SELECT
    w2001.Code AS Code2001,
    w2011.Code AS Code2011,
    w2011.Name
FROM
    w2001 RIGHT JOIN w2011
    ON w2001.Name = w2011.Name;
```

The two `SELECT` statements are similar.  Other than join type, the other difference is that the first returns `w2001.Name` and the second returns `w2011.Name`.

Comment: That query returns the result you requested from your sample data in Access 2007.  However, the row order is not the same.  It would require more work to make the `Code2001` Null sort last.

Answer (score 1):

Like Ben said, the `FULL OUTER JOIN` is probably what you are after.  It returns all rows from the left table `table1` and from the right table `table2`.

The `FULL OUTER JOIN` keyword combines the result of both `LEFT` and `RIGHT` joins.

SQL `FULL OUTER JOIN` Syntax:

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
FULL OUTER JOIN table2
ON table1.column_name=table2.column_name
```

So in your case you are probably needing the following:

```
SELECT w2001.Code AS Code2001, w2011.Code AS Code2011
FROM W2001
FULL OUTER JOIN W2011
ON W2001.Name = W2011.Name
```